# C# How To Use An Event With All Components In The Form

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have 10 buttons my form.
I want to change its fore colors,back colors when i hovered. I don't want to do this with hovered event one by one.
So is it possible to create a funtion(my_hover_func) and use it with the all buttons in the form?

Comment: You can bind an event handler to more than one control.

Comment: You can use a single event handler for all of them. `sender` parameter is the control which raised the event. You can subscribe for the event using designer and also using code.